# Python method move to write file

Tags: python

I want to move the file to the correct folder based on the extension. But my code doesn't work.
the code move the whole folder where the files are contained

```
import os 
import shutil 
import datetime 
import glob 
import time 
import os.path



 def DeplacerDansBonDossier(self):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/administrator/Desktop/TP4/TВlВchargement/"):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith(".txt"):
                    print(os.path.join(root, file))
                    shutil.move("/home/administrator/Desktop/TP4/TВlВchargement/",
                               "/home/administrator/Desktop/TP4/Documents/")
                elif file.endswith(".mp4"):
                    print(os.path.join(root, file))
                    shutil.move("/home/administrator/Desktop/TP4/TВlВchargement/",
                                "/home/administrator/Desktop/TP4/VidВo/")
                elif file.endswith(".mp3" or ".wav"):
                    print(os.path.join(root, file))
                    shutil.move("/home/administrator/Desktop/TP4/TВlВchargement/",
                               "/home/administrator/Desktop/TP4/Musique/")


mon_doc.DeplacerDansBonDossier()
```

Comment: Aside from the `print(...)` call, shouldn't you be using the value from `os.path.join(root, file)` in the call to `shutil.move(...)`?

Comment: as Justin mentioned above. your `shutil.move(...)` call is moving the entire folder to your second mentioned folder instead of the file.